# What happens to a tag when all its questions are gone?

Tags: discussion, tags

When I see stupid tags like [inventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inventions) with only very few questions I usually re-tag them so the tag is empty. I imagine that the tag is then removed after some time and can only be reinstated by someone with the privileges (which hopefully doesn't happen).

Is this assumption correct?

I am asking because I will ask for its removal on meta instead if the tag remained accessible to new (inexperienced) users after having 0 questions for some time .

I'm terribly sorry if an answer to this is already available somewhere. I couldn't find one.